# Understanding HHH90000016 error in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I would like to better understand, and possibly fix, the following warning:

```
2016-07-04 17:04:33,151 WARN  [ajp-nio-8009-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation - toColumns  - HHH90000016: Found use of deprecated 'collection property' syntax in HQL/JPQL query [null.elements]; use collection function syntax instead [elements(null)].
```

It *seems* that my query contains an expression like `? in associatedUsers.elements` where associatedUsers is a `Set<String>`. I have used such expression in the past but eventually changed all them to the new syntax using a filter helper facility.

However debugging showed me that the **real** where expression is

```
((enabled = ?) and (organizationId = ?) and ? in elements(associatedUsers))
```

Why does the error get logged if I already use the suggested syntax? Hibernate version is 5.1.0

Comment: Are you creating this query through HQL or are you doing this through JPQL or Criteria APIs?

Comment: I use an internal helper (**very** similar to Criteria API) that ultimately generates an HQL statement.  The output of that helper is concatenated. `Query query = session.createQuery("from " + getEntityClass().getCanonicalName() + " item " + whereClause + " " + orderBy);`. That **whereClause** is exactly what I posted in my question

Comment: It could be because it is in a `where` clause.  Looking at the code, the deprecation warning will be thrown if it is found not inside a `select` clause fragment.